# two of my component of Adobe CQ5 live copy doesn't have lock

Tags: adobe, aem

in AEM 5.6.1 I've created a live copy from a source page template which has 5 components, out of which I found that 2 components don't have lock all.
I am absolute sure that two these components were not created in the live copy but derived from in the source page itself.

Could you please suggest what can be the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: you need to provide more details...

Comment: two of my components in live copy doesn't have a lock sign at all. They were not created in live copy but came from source file. What could be the possible reason.